# when mouse hover, navdropdown is getting error in React

Tags: reactjs, hover, mouse, nav

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu6dq.png)

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: false };
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root} role="navigation">
        <Navbar className={s.menuBar}>
          <Nav>
            <NavDropdown
              title="Auction"
              id="basic-nav-dropdown"
              onMouseEnter={this.handleOpen}
              onMouseLeave={this.handleClose}
              open={this.state.isOpen}
              noCaret
            >
```

As you can see, I set open prop in NavDropdown.
But at this time, I have faced error as screen shows
If anyone have ever done this, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `defaultOpen` instead of `open` if you are mutating state (and you are). If not, open is asking for a function, maybe try passing your handler instead of the state (I don't think it's the best solution since you are handling the open events with onMouseLeave/Enter)

**With defaultOpen**

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: false };
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root} role="navigation">
        <Navbar className={s.menuBar}>
          <Nav>
            <NavDropdown
              title="Auction"
              id="basic-nav-dropdown"
              onMouseEnter={this.handleOpen}
              onMouseLeave={this.handleClose}
              defaultOpen={this.state.isOpen}
              noCaret
            >
```

**EDIT**

Try this hack to see if it works

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: false };
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root} role="navigation">
        <Navbar className={s.menuBar}>
          <Nav>
            <div
              onMouseEnter={this.handleOpen}
              onMouseLeave={this.handleClose}
            >
            <NavDropdown
              title="Auction"
              id="basic-nav-dropdown"
              defaultOpen={this.state.isOpen}
              noCaret
            >
            </div>
```

You can use a span instead of the div if you want

Comment: Thanks for your answering, Victor.
I have already used 'defautOpen' instead of 'open'.
But at that time, mouse hover doesn't work.
The dropdown is open only when mouse clicking not hovering

Comment: is NavDropDown a component you made? can you show me the code of it?

Comment: If not it's because you are overriding the behaviour of a component, which is not prepared to support what you want to do. I prefer Semantic UI react, for this, It's a really nice and well documented UI library

Comment: I modified my code such as your code.
But at that time, the dropdown effect disappeared.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the whole Nav tag, or adding onMouseEnter/Leave to Nav? If that doesn't work and assuming you're using a library for NavDropDown, just switch to https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown if you don't want to write your own Dropdown. Tell me if it works

Comment: yes, I am using a library for NavDropDown - React-Bootstrap
I am using react-starter-kit and I wonder if what can be the best option for UI framework - Reactstrap or React-Bootstrap or React Material or React Semantic UI